# Netsuite. Saved Search, how to join another table

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I'm trying to make Saved Search which has Transaction fields that I want to join any other type's fields.
When I make Criteria, Result in Saved Search, I realized there is limitation to bring certain field.
I know the Type & Internal ID, so I used formula(numeric) and insert custom_item.realamount(This is actually what I want to know). But this wasn't show a value.
How can I make these two types to join each other?

Answer (score 0):

There is no field in Netsuite called `custom_item` If you are trying to join a custom item field on a transaction search formula field then you'd be looking at a join like

`{item.custitem_uniquepart_}`

Where `_uniquepart_` is either an integer if the custom field was created without a custom id value or it's the value entered for the id field of the custom field.